# How to avoid a breakline after a @Html.TextboxFor in MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to set one div right besides a textbox. My code is like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientID, new { @class = "form-control"})
<div id="check"></div>
```

But although I don't have any breakline, this is what I get

[Div below the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbESk.png)

I would like this div to be on the same line of my textbox.
What can I do?

Comment: Style the `<div>` with css - `#check { display: inline-block; }` (or just make it a `<span>`)

Comment: Or `position:absolute` the `div` and place it wherever you want with `left` and `top` margins